# Displaying Label in opencart based on Category

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to add labels on product list page based on special conditions. I have buy one get one free sale, so When user visits buy 1 get 1 free category, he should be able to see the label on the products(in my case, I have bogo.png image). Everything worked fine with the modifications I did until I searched on the store front for a product, I get undefined variable error.

```
2015-01-09 18:26:58 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: bogo in catalog/view/theme/YourTheme/template/product/product_collection.tpl on line 26
```

I did google search for the problem and browsed opencart forums for days without any luck. So here is what I did until now. On Category.php in catalog/controller file, I added under this array

```
$this->data['products'][]= array(
'bogo'         => $bogo,
```

And added this condition under getProducts specifying if the category id is the category id for the buy 1 get 1 free category set bogo to true.

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
                                if($category_id==977){
                                    $bogo = true;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                    $bogo = false;
                                    }
```

and on product_collection.tpl file, I did this change.

```
<pre><code>
<?php if( $product['bogo'] ) {   ?>         
                            <span class="product-label-bogo2"><img src='bogo.png'></span>
                        <?php } else if ($product['special']) { ?>  
                            <span class="product-label-special"><span><?php echo $this->language->get( 'text_sale' ); ?></span></span>
                        <?php } ?>
</code></pre>
```

Everything is fine if I go to that category it displays the label perfectly, the problem is I get that above error only when I search for anything on store front. 
Please note that before rating the question negatively, I am not familiar at all with php and I did my best with research for hours to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add that piece of code
`if($category_id==977){$bogo = true;}else{$bogo = false;}`
`$this->data['products'][]= array('bogo' => $bogo,`
to **controller/product/search.php** => **ControllerProductSearch@index**

BTW: you will need the add the above code in every controller file that makes use of **product/product_collection.tpl**

Comment: I get the same error when I search when I added that to search.php.

Comment: what is the name of the route of the search page?

Comment: route=product/search which is where i made the change.

Comment: there is no "product/product_collection.tpl" in 1.5.6.1 default theme, are you sure it's a plain version with no extensions?

Comment: /catalog/view/theme/lexus_megashop/template/product/product_collection.tpl Its not a default theme its a custom theme.

Comment: unfortunately I can't check the file because it's a non-free theme, what ever, you need to do the following:
(1) in the view file, get the name of the array that contains $product (most probably there will be a foreach like that [foreach($the_name_we_want as $product)])
(2) in the controller file (product/search.php), search for $this->data['the above name you searched for'][] = array(...
(3) make sure that $bojo is listed in that array
that's the furthest I know based on your error and a half year developing open cart plugins :D, GL !

Comment: Well thanks for your help. I was able to solve the issue after i followed your instructions. First I was adding to a different array. Now It looks fine.

Comment: Actually It worked for the search option, but in manufacturer page,even after repeating similar steps, it doesn't work and in lots of other pages. How do i find out the number of places its being called?

Comment: Welcome to OpenCart world where "Code redundancy" is a design principle :D, unfortunately there is no automated method to know where a specific template is called, you have to search in the whole project for the file using 'ctrl+f'